# My Ubuntu 16.04.1 aptop will not shutdown properly

Tags: shutdown

I recently installed Ubuntu and have one issue that I can't seem to figure out.  When I either shut down my Ubuntu laptop, or if my laptop goes into hibernation, Ubuntu will not completely shut down.  I always have to press and hold the power button for several seconds in order for it to shut down so that I can restart it when I need to do so.  Is there something that can be done to fix this?

Comment: By chance, do you have my-weather-indicator installed? When the shutdown hangs, you might be able to hit the ESC key and a textual screen should appear, and then you can see what the last event was, and help determine why the problem exists.

Comment: No I don't have my-weather-indicator installed.  I am new to Linux Ubuntu and do not know many of the tips and technical shortcuts for it yet.  I will have to try that next time it happens.